# Como utilizar interpolação na declaração de uma propriedade de um tipo?

Tags: typescript

Estou tentando declarar um tipo que aceite diferentes propriedades com um número, por exemplo: `prop1`, `prop2` ... `propN`. O ponto é que não estou conseguindo fazer com que isso se comporte da maneira esperada, e não estou entendendo o porquê.

O código abaixo foi testado na versão 4.3.5 do TypeScript:

```
type Props = {
  [K in `prop${number}`]: boolean;
};

const myString = 'a';
const myNumber = 32;

const obj: Props = {
  prop15: true,
  propA: false,
  [`prop${myNumber}`]: true,
  [`prop${myString}`]: false,
  anything: 137,
}

const obj2: Props = {};

const someNumber: Props = 32;
```

<sup>Veja no [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgbQGkoBLAOygAMxEwASTMgVwFsAjCOAX0oF0AuKGwQIANhACGZANzYus7AGMEZZMCgsQAZWBxyAc3RQA5BOOzlq9ZoByrDnCMBmAEwLLaqAjYArQfCRUDBw8GiQARgBWQV0mCAAaXCgwsABBQQAzCVFkBKT8aloGW3tOHgEoWLy8ApTi7V0Dcszs3MS8KRBgAAsDQXCnAHZErmwlFU9vHxd-WiCseTGPdWQEFgg7dk5ZwOc3bCA).</sup>

Mas parece que esse `type` não está servindo de nada. Nenhuma das declarações do código acima deu erro. Inclusive, quando coloco o cursor sobre `Props`, aparece `type Props = {}`.

- O que esse tipo tem de errado, que está aceitando qualquer coisa?
- Tem algum jeito de fazer o que eu preciso? Criar um tipo que permita `prop1`, `prop2` ... `propN` e nada mais?

Comment: Mas qual o _use-case_ para isso? Não me faz muito sentido tipar um objeto onde diversas das infinitas possíveis propriedades não existiriam. Nesse caso, não faz mais sentido usar um `unknown`?

Comment: De todo modo, o fato de nenhum erro ser reportado ao tentar utilizar um conjunto infinito gerador de chaves para um objeto me parece um bug do compilador. Sei que não é a mesma coisa, mas veja o erro que é emitido [neste caso](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIlC8UDkAGJUA+yCM6tICY9kBmYpAFnIFYkBuAKFEigHUFkBBcgIXIGFyMcgFFyAMXoMm4aACUIAZw4ADACQBvGAF8AtJtZ7NO-RsOmTBo1u0q6QA).

Comment: O use-case: estou usando validação do express-validator com [wildcards](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/wildcards.html), algo como `'addresses.*.postalCode'` que me retornaria um objeto de erro `addresses[posição].postalCode`. Não me parece um bom nome para propriedade, mas por enquanto tenho deixado assim e estava tentando criar um tipo para isso, quando me deparei com o problema descrito na pergunta. Me parece que o TypeScript 4.4 tem [algo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797) que talvez resolvesse isso, mas não consegui usá-lo corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta

```
type Props = {
  [K: `props${number}`]: boolean;
};
```

Tambem, esse tipo de types **Template Literal Types** so funcionam com a versão do **typescript 4.4** e acima.

***ATUALIZAÇÂO***
Esta resposta não pega o erro `` [`props${myString}`]: false, ``

Comment: Na verdade isto é do TypeScript 4.4, não? Enfim, eu testei e ainda não funciona plenamente conforme o esperado, veja no [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgbQGkAuKAAzETABJMA7AVwFsAjCOAXzIF1SWEEAGwgBDOgG5sHSdgDGCOsmBQmIAMrA4ASzoBzdFADkIw5PmLlqgHLM2cAwGYATDPNKoCFgCtS8JKgwcPEokAEYAVlJNBggAGlwoELAAQVIAMxFBZDiE-AoqWmtbdi5eKGicvDykwvVNHV1S9Mzs+LwxEGAACwbSUIcAdniObDkFd08vJ18qAKxpUbdlZAQmCBtWdhn-RxdsIA). No exemplo da pergunta, não aponta um erro para `[\`prop${myString}\`]: false`, você sabe dizer o porquê?

Comment: Na realidade parece que qualquer string concatenado, incluído `['sdsdf'+'sdfsd']: false,` não gera um erro. Interessante. Vou dar mais umas pesquisadas.

Comment: Posso fazer sua pergunta no SO em Ingles?  Coloco um link para essa. @RafaelTavares

Comment: Claro, mas não faz sentido colocar o link, já que aqui está em português. E é mais adequado escrever a dúvida com suas palavras, pois seu nível de entendimento do problema pode ser diferente do meu. Não sei se o TypeScript aceita perguntas no repositório do GitHub, vale dar uma olhada também.

Comment: aqui esta o link para pergunta que fiz.  Atualizo minha resposta se alguem descobrir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954369/template-literal-types-no-working-with-string-concatenation. @RafaelTavares